# Hiding and showing HTML elements based on what a string contains

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help figuring out how to hide / show an HTML element based on whether a string includes a word.

In the style tag I have:

```
#Assignment-1 {
  display:none;
}

#Assignment-2 {
  display:none;
}

#Assignment-3 {
  display:none;
}
```

At the bottom before the ending body tag I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var str = "Artist, Special"

   if($(str.includes("Artist")){
     document.getElementById('Assignment-1').style.display = "block";
   }

   if($(str.includes("Release")){
     document.getElementById('Assignment-2').style.display = "block";
   }

   if($(str.includes("Special")){
     document.getElementById('Assignment-3').style.display = "block";
   }

</script>
```

Comment: what's the question? I mean, I would remove the '$()' wrapper around str.includes - but is something not working?

Comment: Please elaborate on what your question or what you are specifically having issues with and please provide the html you are using.  It makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: It should be ```var str = ["Artist", "Special"]``` ?

Comment: Hi! My Q is how do I hide / show an HTML element based on whether a string includes a word.

Comment: @Kyle is correct, remove the '$()' wrapper around str.includes and it works.

Comment: Hello! Could you add the HTML too? Anyway for what you posted here:
- If `$` is jQuery you don't need it in this case 
- Please, check the number of parenthesis in your `if` condition, there is one too many
After that everything should work

Comment: Kyle was right! You beautiful man. It's working now. My script wasn't making those elements appear but once I removed the $() it worked. THANK YOU!! Sorry I'm not so great at asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a `$(` before your if-condition? Remove those characters.

```js
var str = "Artist, Special";

if (str.includes("Artist")) {
  document.getElementById('Assignment-1').style.display = "block";
}

if (str.includes("Release")) {
  document.getElementById('Assignment-2').style.display = "block";
}

if (str.includes("Special")) {
  document.getElementById('Assignment-3').style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#Assignment-1 { display: none; }
#Assignment-2 { display: none; }
#Assignment-3 { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="Assignment-1">Assignment 1</div>
<div id="Assignment-2">Assignment 2</div>
<div id="Assignment-3">Assignment 3</div>
```

A better approach would be to use a class name:

```js
const str = "Artist, Special";
const assignments = document.querySelectorAll('.assignment');

assignments[0].classList.toggle('show', str.includes("Artist"));
assignments[1].classList.toggle('show', str.includes("Release"));
assignments[2].classList.toggle('show', str.includes("Special"));
```

```css
.assignment { display: none; }
.show       { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="assignment">Assignment 1</div>
<div class="assignment">Assignment 2</div>
<div class="assignment">Assignment 3</div>
```